# Flutter Error: Unable to find git in you path - Have added all the env variables

Tags: windows, git, flutter, environment-variables, flutter-dependencies

On running the command flutter or flutter doctor on Windows 10.
I get **Error: Unable to find git in your path**

git is installed

```
C:\Users\drake>git --version
git version 2.12.2.windows.2
```

I have tried literally all the questions and GitHub discussions, even restarted the system multiple times, yet the issue exists.

I have added the environment variables in system and even in user variables same as in the below screenshot maintaining the order suggested by other answers.

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is git installed?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon 
C:\Users\drake>where git
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` shouldn't be in the PATH. `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` should.